# res.render with href but not with jquery http get

Tags: jquery, node.js

I am new to Node.JS and writing a program on expressjs. I have an app.js node program with following route

```
app.get('/registration2',function(req,res) {
    console.log("app.js");
    res.render('registration2');
});
```

This works fine when I use it from menu using

```
<li><a href="/registration2">Become Member</a></li>
```

but when I call similar using jQuery it doesn't render page registration.

```
app.get('/pr1/:price?',function(req,res) {
    var  price = req.params.price;
    console.log(price);
    res.render('registration2');
});
```

I used console.log(price) just to check whether it is capturing variable price correctly and i found that console.log does show correct result

My jQuery is as follows:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $.get("/pr1/499");
        alert("OK");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You're didn't pass a callback function to [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) so it just ignores the result.

Comment: I am very new to this and reading various document, please help me in understanding  on your comment

Answer (score 0):

You're using [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) wrong. Just doing `$.get("/pr1/499")` only makes a request. You have to pass it a second argument, which has to be a function that will be executed once it gets back the result of the request.

```
$.get("/pr1/499", function callback(data){
    console.log(data); // `data` is the returned HTML
});
```

Here the callback function is one that's executed at a later time, asynchronously, when the result from the request made by jQuery is received.
It will be called automatically with an argument `data` which will contain the result.

Comment: Thank you, but then why it is not required when i use only href ?

Comment: I made the changes, but program is still not working

Comment: href and $.get are fundamentally different things. How is it not working? Does the data not show up in the console?

Comment: console.log shows value of variable price, but it doesnt render page registration2

Comment: That means $.get is working. You're choosing wrong way to do what you actually want to achieve. You need to learn at least the basics of [DOM manipulation in Javascript](http://google.com/search?q=dom+manipulation+tutorial+%28javascript%29) before using jquery.

Comment: I know that i have to learn a lot on basic DOM, but If my program is getting to correct route /pr1, the route is getting the correct value of price (499), in jquery alert is showing write message and console.log is showing passed value, does it still indicate that $.get not working ?

Comment: $.get is working. But using it all by itself wouldn't render the page for you, it just fetches the page and stores it in the `data` variable.

Comment: I found that it is rendering the page but entire code (html) is getting passed to alert of my jquery

Comment: going through number of questions and answers by expert , looks like , the page cant be rendered by expressJS res.render. I was able to render the page using window.location.href = data in jQuery, and data is being returned page name  response from expressjs res.render. Simpler could be directly get page on jQuery (Unless I have to derive page name and other variables from expressjs.  Appreciate comments from other on my understanding